# How to enable Arrow-Up (and Arrow-Down) key to show previous (or next) entered line in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

> How to enable Arrow-Up (and Arrow-Down) key to show previous (or next) entered line in Emacs?

In Emacs, particular in Scheme mode, I want to use the `ArrowUp` and `ArrowDown` keys to navigate in the history or entered commmands, like I use to do in Bash.

However, pressing these keys in the Scheme interpreter (running inside Emacs) doesn't do anything except to go up or down one line in the buffer.

I guess the way to enable this history navigation applies to all modes?

[image]

I want to go the expression above i.e. `'(1 2 3)`.

How do I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get into the command buffer to get history of commands. Press `M-x` and then try <kbd>Up</kbd> /<kbd>Down</kbd>. When you are in a regular buffer, these are indeed navigation keys.

Also. have a look at `Helm`.

Edit (to sync the answer with the updated question, pulling the updated answer from the comments)

If the intention is to use history in the Lisp interpreter buffer, then `C-up` and `C-down` are the usual key bindings for that.

Comment: Try Ctrl-Up/Ctrl-Down.Can't test it with Scheme at the moment but it normally works with all other interpreters.

Comment: `C-h b` in any buffer to see all the current keybindings.  It can be a pretty long list, but you can use isearch in it, and it's generally broken down by mode.